# Why Reactive Spring, Kotlin Coroutine use Cancellable as default?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm developing a new Rest API with Kotlin, Spring. And I recently realized that the API calls on the endpoint like below could be cancelled when a client shut down the connection:

```
@RestController
class UserController(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {

    @PostMapping("/")
    suspend fun save(user: User) =
        userRepository.save(user)
}
```

So, my question is

1. For me, it seems risky to use cancellable coroutine in the application because it can cause partial write or partial processing of the code. So, why do they support cancellable as a default when building reactive app with Kotlin and Spring?
2. Is there any way to globally set the root coroutine as nonCancellable?
   2-1. If it's possible, isn't there any drawback?
3. Can you give me a concrete Reactive Spring Rest API code example including critical processing with nonCancellable?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cancelled coroutines get cancelled at points where they support cancellation. This can be at certain suspend function calls (`delay()`, `yield()`, `suspendCoroutine()`, etc.) or where they manually break after an isActive check. It will not interrupt an asynchronous task or synchronous IO function. For it to result in a partial write, the implementation of the writing code would have to be broken up into multiple write calls with suspend function yield calls or isActive checks in between.

Comment: I don't know Spring, but in other libraries I've worked with, they aren't designed this way. Most likely, Spring is designed in Java, and the suspend functions are wrappers around asynchronous Java functions, so coroutine cancellation would not cancel these suspend function tasks in the middle once initiated.

Comment: Oh, I'll check it with your answers

Comment: So, you mean if there're so many 'suspend fun' in the 'suspend fun save(user: User)', then client cancellation can make partial execution of the 'suspend fun' in it. That point makes me confused, it's common to make application with 'suspend fun' and Spring, then why they make cancellable as a default?

Comment: As a controller, it seems that it is doing its job, as an HTTP request can be canceled and so its process should be stopped. It seems that you need to use a different approach to get the right behavior. There are several ways to do so: 1. use transaction if your database and database driver support it. 2. trigger an async process that performs the code.

Comment: Oh,  'suspend fun' seems not to be a 'point that support cancellation'. So, client connection cancel does not affect the API with pure tasks only with 'suspend fun'. But it's hard to distinguish which one will gonna be the points that support cancellation (what cooperative means https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative)

Comment: Since they probably generate the suspend function using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` (one of the standard library functions that cooperates with cancellation) it should be expected that cancellation can stop the coroutine just before or just after this suspend function is called, but not in the middle of its task.

Answer (score 0):

The point is which one is a cooperative and cancellable function.

In below, client's cancel does not cancel task execution included in the endpoint:
[image]

But below is affected, because 'delay' is cancellable function:
[image]